# Windows 10 Assigned Access Sideloaded App Not Shown

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to create a kiosk application for a Windows 10 Pro tablet.

On the device I have a dedicated local user account. Under that account I have sideloaded a Universal Windows app I created using the PowerShell Add-AppxPackage command. The app is installed and runs just fine.

However, when I log on as the administrator and try to setup Assigned Access I can select the dedicated local user account but the application list is empty.

I have signed out and back into the dedicated account after installing the application. The device was not in Assigned Access mode at the time.

I'm stumped as to what secret bit I missed to get my application to show up on the list of available applications for assigned access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer. Buried in a post from Microsoft the application manifest needs to have the "windows.aboveLockScreen" extension added.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt633799(v=vs.85).aspx

```
<Extensions>
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.lockScreenCall" />
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.aboveLockScreen" />
</Extensions>
```